# How to copy a 2D array to a RenderScript Allocation in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, renderscript

I try to pass a 2D float array to RenderScript, but the app keep crash.

```
val a = arrayOf(floatArrayOf(1f, 2f, 3f), floatArrayOf(4f, 5f, 6f))
val typeBuilder = Type.Builder(rs, Element.F32(rs))
val aAlloc: Allocation = Allocation.createTyped(rs, typeBuilder.create())
aAlloc.copy2DRangeFrom(0, 0, 3, 2, a)
```

The app crashed at the last line, with this error:

> android.renderscript.RSIllegalArgumentException: Object passed is not
> an Array of primitives.

Comment: Hi, there is no signature with 2d array 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/renderscript/Allocation#copy2DRangeTo(int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20float[])

Answer (score 0):

Heres an example method which fills any allocation with 0's.

```
public static void fillWithZeros(Allocation allocation) {
    int size = allocation.getType().getCount();
    switch (allocation.getElement().getDataType()) {

        case SIGNED_8:
        case UNSIGNED_8:
            size *= allocation.getType().getElement().getBytesSize();
            byte[] zeroArray8 = new byte[size];
            allocation.copyFrom(zeroArray8);
            break;

        case SIGNED_16:
        case UNSIGNED_16:
            size *= allocation.getType().getElement().getBytesSize() / 2;
            short[] zeroArray16 = new short[size];
            allocation.copyFrom(zeroArray16);
            break;

        case SIGNED_32:
        case UNSIGNED_32:
            size *= allocation.getType().getElement().getBytesSize() / 4;
            int[] zeroArray32 = new int[size];
            allocation.copyFrom(zeroArray32);
            break;

        case FLOAT_32:
            size *= allocation.getType().getElement().getBytesSize() / 4;
            float[] zeroArrayF32 = new float[size];
            allocation.copyFrom(zeroArrayF32);
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}
```